# Difference between null composite type and composite type with all null columns

Tags: postgresql, null, distinct, postgresql-9.6, row-value-expression

Is there any difference between a null value and a row type where all columns are null? Postgres queries appear to be able to tell the difference (displaying null columns rather than a blank) and I want to know if there's anything I should be aware of. e.g.

```
CREATE TYPE node AS (
   rank integer
 , id integer
);

CREATE TABLE hierarchy (
   node node
);

INSERT INTO hierarchy (node) VALUES (null);
INSERT INTO hierarchy (node) VALUES ((null, null));

SELECT *, node IS NULL AS check_null FROM hierarchy;
```

> ```
>  node | check_null
> ------+------------
>       | t
>  (,)  | t
> ```

Comment: Check your database design, because a row where all columns are NULL has not sense in the relational model. You always need a unique primary key to identify each row in a table. A row can have some NULL fields, but the primary key of a row never shouldn't be NULL.

Comment: @aicastell Read rowtype in the question as composite type.

Comment: Your question has numerous syntax errors (and semantic errors as well, f.ex. node is both a composite type & a table name). Are you sure you ran those? http://rextester.com/ZMOO91035

Comment: The weird behavior of `(NULL, NULL) IS NULL` comes from the SQL standard. But actually it is quite handy, when dealing with `OUTER JOIN`s.

Comment: What you show is impossible. A table and a composite type cannot have the same name. Please fix your question to make sense. And *always* declare the Postgres version you are working with.

Comment: @posz Thanks - tidied up and now makes sense.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> **Is there any difference between a null value and a rowtype where all the columns are null?**

`NULL:node` is still distinct from `(null, null)::node`:

```
SELECT null::node IS DISTINCT FROM (null, null)::node AS dist;
```

> ```
> dist
> ----
> t
> ```

I agree this is confusing. And [the manual might be sharpened here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-comparison.html), too:

> For non-null inputs, `IS DISTINCT FROM` is the same as the `<>` operator.
>   However, if both inputs are null it returns false, and if only one
>   input is null it returns true.

Turns out to be slightly incorrect in the face of above demo. Even though there is a hint further down:

> If the `expression` is row-valued, then `IS NULL` is true when the row
>   expression itself is null or when all the row's fields are null.

So we have *two* distinct cases in which a row value is null:

1. expression itself is null.
2. all the row's fields are null.

It should be mentioned that these two cases are still considered ***distinct***, when compared with `IS DISTINCT FROM`. May be worth a documentation bug report ...

> **anything I should be aware of?**

Yes. Wherever `DISTINCT` comes into play, both variants are considered, well, distinct:

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM hierarchy;
```

> ```
>  node1
> ------
>  (,)  
>
> (2 rows)
> ```

Note the 2nd invisible row, because psql displays null values this way.

> **To stop the (,) case from occurring ?**

Addressing your comment:

```
CREATE TABLE hierarchy (
  node node CHECK (node IS DISTINCT FROM (null, null)::node)
);
```

Note two things:

1. The explicit cast `(null, null)::node` is necessary.
2. Simple NULL values are still allowed, only a row with all null values violates the constraint.

Comment: And I so to stop the `(,)` case from occuring I'd have to add a `CHECK (node1 IS DISTINCT FROM (null, null))` constraint?

Comment: @dbeacham: Yes, but you need an explicit type cast. I added more above.

Comment: Other cases where this distinction is important are declaring a column as `NOT NULL` or using `COALESCE`. Probably more…