# PostgreSQL `IS NOT NULL` does not work properly for composite types

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, sql-null, composite-types

I am trying to create a function which should map the table row to my user-defined type (which is a composite type) and return that as a result. If some column in that table is NULL, then `IS NOT NULL` check on my custom type does not work!

#### Example

I have a simple composite type:

```sql
CREATE TYPE my_custom_type AS (
  sender VARCHAR(30),
  destination VARCHAR(30),
  count INTEGER
);
```

And a table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE messages (
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  sender VARCHAR(30),
  destination VARCHAR(30),
  count INTEGER
);
```

Insert single row for this example:

```sql
INSERT INTO messages VALUES (1, 'sender', 'destination', 100);
```

And now I want to create a function which will return that row as a custom Postgres type:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_custom_function() 
RETURNS my_custom_type AS
$$
DECLARE
    result my_custom_type;
BEGIN

    SELECT sender, destination, count
    FROM messages
    LIMIT 1
    INTO result;

    IF result IS NULL THEN
        RAISE EXCEPTION 'no data';
    END IF;

    RETURN result;

END; $$
    LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I get expected results when I use this function:

```sql
SELECT * from my_custom_function();
```

[image]

But unexpected behaviors start to occur when some column is updated to NULL:

```sql
UPDATE messages SET destination = NULL;
```

When I execute the function again, it still returns good results:
[image]

But if I change the `IS NULL` condition to `IS NOT NULL` condition:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_custom_function() 
RETURNS my_custom_type AS
$$
DECLARE
    result my_custom_type;
BEGIN

    SELECT sender, destination, count
    FROM messages
    LIMIT 1
    INTO result;

    IF result IS NOT NULL THEN
        RETURN result;
    END IF;

    RAISE EXCEPTION 'no data';

END; $$
    LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Then I got an error:
**ERROR:  no data**

Can someone please explain me why this does not work? It makes no sense to me...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A composite type `IS NULL` if **all** its elements are NULL, and it `IS NOT NULL` if **all** elements are not NULL.

That is required by the SQL standard.

This has unpleasant consequences, for example is `x IS NOT NULL` not the same as `NOT x IS NULL` for composite types. Also, two values that both return `TRUE` for the `IS NULL` test can be distinct:

```
SELECT ROW(NULL, NULL) IS DISTINCT FROM NULL;

 ?column? 
══════════
 t
(1 row)
```

The SQL standard clearly didn't do a good job there. Read [this thread from the pgsql-hackers list](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/20090724165614.GD5407%40samason.me.uk#ceac6c3417e927c4c9627e1ea443c39c) for further <strike>edification</strike>confusion.

Comment: Relevant: [Difference between null composite type and composite type with all null columns](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43187305/1048572)

Comment: @Bergi Yes. I added some juicy morsels.

Comment: ahh, the "and it IS NOT NULL if all elements are not NULL" part makes sense... but also very frustrated - because I did not think of it.